# The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, localhost, mamp, htdocs

I have got a problem with my testing localhost site, which it appears on Safari with a blank page, and on Chrome which says The localhost page isn’t working

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

I have checked php.ini and have already modified some code to `error_reporting = E_ALL`, and `display_errors = On` but the same problem is still happened.

I also looked at the problem on Terminal and I got it for

> [27-Dec-2016 19:56:53 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/orithaic/domains/orithai.co.th/public_html/e-commerce/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Orithai/e-commerce/index.php on line 17

Does anyone know how to fix this problem with the server?

Comment: Did you checked if file /home/orithaic/domains/orithai.co.th/public_html/e-commerce/system/startup.php exist or not?

Comment: Error clearly says that **No such file or directory** , please check the path,

Comment: Is `/home/orithaic/domains/orithai.co.th/public_html/e-commerce/...` hardcoded in your `index.php` file?

Comment: @ piyush, yes the file  /home/orithaic/domains/orithai.co.th/public_html/e-commerce/‌​system/startup.php exist.

Comment: @Punit, I don't know how to fix the path.

Comment: @Ross Wilson, hardcoded is also in index.php which says: // Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'); Is that correct?